# How to remove first array element using the spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

So I have an array, ex. `const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];`. I'd like to use the spread syntax `...` to remove the first element.

ie. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` ==> `[2, 3, 4]`

Can this be done with the spread syntax?

Edit: Simplified the question for a more general use case.

Comment: Why not just use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead? `arr.splice(1,1)` should do what you're asking

Comment: Or even `arr.shift()`

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use these methods, I just wanted to learn more about the `...` specifically

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure you can.

```js
const xs = [1,2,3,4];

const tail = ([x, ...xs]) => xs;

console.log(tail(xs));
```

Is that what you're looking for?

---

You originally wanted to remove the second element which is simple enough:

```js
const xs = [1,0,2,3,4];

const remove2nd = ([x, y, ...xs]) => [x, ...xs];

console.log(remove2nd(xs));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Learned a lot about the `...` operator through these answers

Answer (score 13):

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

[, ...a] = a

console.log( a )
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
const input = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4];
const output = [input[0], ...input.slice(2)];
```

After the question was updated:

```
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const output = [...input.slice(1)];
```

But this is silly, because you can just do:

```
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const output = input.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *rest* operator `(...arrOutput)` with the spread `operator(...arr)`.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const [itemRemoved, ...arrOutput] = [...arr];
console.log(arrOutput);
```